# C++ vs C# bitwise operations on 64-bit ints - performance

Tags: c#, c++, performance, comparison, bitwise-operators

I have 2D field of bits stored in an array of 5 unsigned longs.
I am going for the best performance.
I am working in C# but I tried to set a benchmark by implementing my class in C++.

The problem here is that the C# implementation takes about 10 seconds to finish where the C++ takes about 1 second making it **10 times faster**. C++ is x64 build in VS2015. C# is in x64 VS2015 .NET 4.6. Both in Release of course.

**EDIT:** After optimizing the C# code a little it still takes 7 to 8 seconds vs C++ 1.3 seconds.

**Note:** C++ in x86 takes about 6 seconds to finish. I am running the code on 64-bit machine.

**Question:** What makes the C++ THAT much faster? And is there a way to optimize the C# code to be at least similarly fast? (Maybe some unsafe magic?)

What puzzles me is that we are talking just about iterating through arrays and bitwise operations. Shouldn't it be JITed to pretty much the same thing as C++?

**Example code:**
There are two simple functions in the implementation. Left() and Right() shifting the whole filed by 1 bit to the left resp. right with appropriate bit carrying between the longs.

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class BitField
{
private:
    unsigned long long LEFTMOST_BIT = 0x8000000000000000;
    unsigned long long RIGHTMOST_BIT = 1;

public:
    unsigned long long Cells_l[5];
    BitField()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Cells_l[i] = rand(); // Random initialization
        }
    }
    void Left()
    {
        unsigned long long carry = 0;
        unsigned long long nextCarry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            nextCarry = (Cells_l[i] & LEFTMOST_BIT) >> 63;
            Cells_l[i] = Cells_l[i] << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
        }
    }
    void Right()
    {
        unsigned long long carry = 0;
        unsigned long long nextCarry = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            nextCarry = (Cells_l[i] & RIGHTMOST_BIT) << 63;
            Cells_l[i] = Cells_l[i] >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    BitField bf;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        bf.Left();
        bf.Left();
        bf.Left();
        bf.Right();
        bf.Right();
        bf.Left();
        bf.Right();
        bf.Right();
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

    cout << "Time: " << duration << endl << endl;
    // Print to avoid compiler optimizations
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << bf.Cells_l[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestCS
{
    class BitField
    {
        const ulong LEFTMOST_BIT = 0x8000000000000000;
        const ulong RIGHTMOST_BIT = 1;

        static Random rnd = new Random();

        ulong[] Cells;

        public BitField()
        {
            Cells = new ulong[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Cells[i] = (ulong)rnd.Next(); // Random initialization
            }
        }

        public void Left()
        {
            ulong carry = 0;
            ulong nextCarry = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                nextCarry = (Cells[i] & LEFTMOST_BIT) >> 63;
                Cells[i] = Cells[i] << 1 | carry;
                carry = nextCarry;
            }
        }
        public void Right()
        {
            ulong carry = 0;
            ulong nextCarry = 0;
            for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nextCarry = (Cells[i] & RIGHTMOST_BIT) << 63;
                Cells[i] = Cells[i] >> 1 | carry;
                carry = nextCarry;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BitField bf = new BitField();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            // Call to remove the compilation time from measurements
            bf.Left();
            bf.Right();

            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                bf.Left();
                bf.Left();
                bf.Left();
                bf.Right();
                bf.Right();
                bf.Left();
                bf.Right();
                bf.Right();
            }
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Done in: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()}ms");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed "nextCarry" typos in example code.

Comment: To start with, print the Cells_l values at the end of your C++, to rule out any possibilty of code removal due to optimizations (unused values => unused calculations => unused functions... below a certain complexity, everything can be removed) ... Such a big time difference would surpise me too, if it is real.

Comment: In C++ loops end terminals are fixed and in C# you call Cells.Length each time.

Comment: @deviantfan Compiler optimization was my first thought. But the times remain the same even if I print Cells_l in the end.

Comment: One difference is that the C++ code works with an array embedded in the struct known to be at a fixed address, while the C# code has a reference to a separate array on the heap. I guess "Cells[i]" gets dereferenced (and bounds checked) each time, since the heap may have been GC'd between accesses.To duplicate the C++ code you could make "class Bitfield" into a "public unsafe struct Bitfield", change Cells to "public fixed ulong Cells[5]" then use "fixed(ulong *" to access it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette Replacing Cells.Length by constants gives a few percent but nothing significant.

Comment: To make sure there is no loops optimization in C++, try to initialize your `Cells`/`Cells_l` arrays with random values instead of a constant value.

Comment: @Dmitry Random numbers made it a little worse for c++. Something like 1100 ms vs 1300 ms.

Comment: @dxiv is right, I deleted my answer as I found it misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got enough information from comments and a deleted answer from @AntoninLejsek that I can answer this myself.

**TL;DR** C++ compiler does much better job optimizing and C# managed array access costs a lot when done in loop. However unsafe code and fixed access is not enough to match C++.

It seems we need to optimize the C# code manually to get performance comparable to C++.

1. Unroll loops
2. Use unsafe code for fixed array access
3. Don't access the array repeatedly - rather store the item into local variable.

Following C# code runs as fast as C++ code (about 100 ms faster in fact). Compiled on .NET 4.6 VS 2015 Release x64.

```
unsafe struct BitField
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public fixed ulong Cells[5];
    public BitField(int nothing)
    {
        fixed (ulong* p = Cells)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                p[i] = (ulong)rnd.Next(); // Just some random number
            }
        }
    }
public void StuffUnrolledNonManaged()
{
        ulong u0;
        ulong u1;
        ulong u2;
        ulong u3;
        ulong u4;
        fixed (ulong *p = Cells)
        {
            u0 = p[0];
            u1 = p[1];
            u2 = p[2];
            u3 = p[3];
            u4 = p[4];
        }
        ulong carry = 0;
        ulong nextCarry = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {

            //left
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u0 >> 63;
            u0 = u0 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 >> 63;
            u1 = u1 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 >> 63;
            u2 = u2 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 >> 63;
            u3 = u3 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u4 = u4 << 1 | carry;

            //left
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u0 >> 63;
            u0 = u0 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 >> 63;
            u1 = u1 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 >> 63;
            u2 = u2 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 >> 63;
            u3 = u3 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u4 = u4 << 1 | carry;

            //left
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u0 >> 63;
            u0 = u0 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 >> 63;
            u1 = u1 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 >> 63;
            u2 = u2 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 >> 63;
            u3 = u3 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u4 = u4 << 1 | carry;

            //right
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u4 << 63;
            u4 = u4 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 << 63;
            u3 = u3 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 << 63;
            u2 = u2 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 << 63;
            u1 = u1 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u0 = u0 >> 1 | carry;

            //right
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u4 << 63;
            u4 = u4 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 << 63;
            u3 = u3 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 << 63;
            u2 = u2 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 << 63;
            u1 = u1 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u0 = u0 >> 1 | carry;

            //left
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u0 >> 63;
            u0 = u0 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 >> 63;
            u1 = u1 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 >> 63;
            u2 = u2 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 >> 63;
            u3 = u3 << 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u4 = u4 << 1 | carry;

            //right
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u4 << 63;
            u4 = u4 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 << 63;
            u3 = u3 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 << 63;
            u2 = u2 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 << 63;
            u1 = u1 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u0 = u0 >> 1 | carry;

            //right
            carry = 0;
            nextCarry = u4 << 63;
            u4 = u4 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u3 << 63;
            u3 = u3 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u2 << 63;
            u2 = u2 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            nextCarry = u1 << 63;
            u1 = u1 >> 1 | carry;
            carry = nextCarry;
            u0 = u0 >> 1 | carry;

        }

        fixed (ulong* p = Cells)
        {
            p[0] = u0;
            p[1] = u1;
            p[2] = u2;
            p[3] = u3;
            p[4] = u4;
        }
    }
```

**Testing code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BitField bf = new BitField(0);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            // Call to remove the compilation time from measurements
            bf.StuffUnrolledNonManaged();

            sw.Start();
            bf.StuffUnrolledNonManaged();
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Non managed access unrolled in: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()}ms");
        }
```

This code finishes in about **1.1 seconds**.

**Note:** Only fixed array access is not enough to match the C++ performance. If we don't use the local variables - every instance of u0 is replaced by p[0] etc.. The time is about **3.6 seconds**.

If we use only fixed access with the code from question (calling Left() and Right() functions in loop). The time is about **5.8 seconds**.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the difference may be because of the differences in code between the two versions - you don't assign to `nextCarry` in the C++ `Left` nor in the C# `Right`, but those could be typos in the example.

You'd want to look at the disassembly of both to see the difference, but primarily it is due to the C++ compiler having more time to spend optimizing the code.  In this case it unrolls the loops, inlines all the function calls (including the constructor), and shoves all of the stuff in `Cells_l` into registers.  So there's one big loop using registers and no accesses to memory.

I haven't looked at the C# compiled output but I doubt it does anything close to that.

Also, as mentioned in a comment, replace all the `Cells.Length` calls in your C# code to 5 (just like you have in the C++ code).

Comment: I have tried to "inline" the functions in C# to avoid the calling overhead, but that made worse than better. The nextCarry is a typo indeed.